# Filter list of strings if a keyword matches in another list using Ramda

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js, pure-function

I have a list of URLs that have been returned from an API:

```
const data = [
  '/shoutouts',
  '/shoutouts/shoutout',
  '/news/news-story',
  '/example-page',
  '/another-page',
  '/stories/what-s-next',
  '/metrics',
  '/links',
  '/links/sprint',
  '/quick-links',
  '/quick-links/confluence'
]
```

And I have a some categories that I’d like to filter my URLs with:

```
const filters = [
  'news',
  'shoutouts',
  'quick-links',
  'metrics',
  'links'
]
```

I’d like to be left only with URLs that contain a category name in. For example, if one of the URLs contains `links` or `news`, we’d like to keep it.

This is the (not working) code idea I have so far.

```
const containsFilter = (filter, data) => R.contains(filter, data)

const filtered = R.map(filter => {
  return R.filter(containsFilter(filter, data))
}, filters)
```

How might I adapt this in a more pure/ramda-esque way to filter my URL list?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using R.filter instead of R.map? map would still return array of same length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
const filtered = R.filter(url => {
  return R.any((filter) => {
    return R.contains(filter, url);
  }, filters);
}, data);
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution with just plain JS:

```
const filtered = data.reduce((res, curr) => filters.some(f => curr.includes(f)) ? res.concat(curr) : res, [])
```